# How to store a huge number in C string?

Tags: c, string

I want store a positive integer up to 10^500000 in a string.

But I don't know what should I write of the size of string.

```
char in[?????];
```

Just like that.

I tried to write something like this.

```
char in[sizeof(long double)];
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Simply `char in[500002]`? (do not forget to allocate space for terminating null-character when you want to deal with *C-string*)

Comment: @MikeCAT OP wants 10 ^ 500000

Comment: it will depend on the base you will use.

Comment: @machine_1 I think 500001 characters (1 as the most significant digit + 500000 zeros) will be enough to store positive integers upto `pow(10, 500000)`. Do you mean OP wants 500010 (10 xor 500000) or am I wrong?

Comment: @MikeCAT 10 to the power 500,000 is 1 and 500,000 zeros next to it

Comment: thx u guys helping me,i think i solve that problem

Comment: Then post an answer to your own question so people will learn from it, or edit your question :)

Comment: @PvzAKho if my answer below answers your question then please select it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store long decimal numbers as strings, you need figure (no pun intended) out how many (base 10) digits they have.  In your case, 10^500000 has 500,001 digits, so you will need a character string of length 500,002, to include the terminating `'\0'`.

`char in[500002];` if you know how long the numbers are in advance...